# Troubles with ports after docker-compose restart

Tags: docker, sockets, docker-compose

I have an issue with ports after running command `docker-compose restart` - containers can't use ports and can't open socket. If I run `docker-compose stop + run` - everything works as expected.

Does anyone run into the same problem?

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. For people to be able to help you, you should post a bit more information: What commands exactly did you run? What errors did you see? How does your docker-compose file look?

Comment: Have you tried with `--force-recreate` option?

Comment: `docker-compose restart` doesn't support option `--force-recreate`